# Example 7.4 from Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

I read this example from Rudin's book but I can't understand what did he show by this example. Can anyone answer what does he mean by following?[image]

Comment: What part specifically are you are having trouble with?

Comment: @Mattos, I understand all details. He get limit function (Dirichlet function) which is discontinuous everywhere and is not integrable by Riemann. But I can't understand sequence of functions $\{f_m(x)\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is continuous or not?

Comment: Are you asking which idea this is supposed to be a counterexample to? That would require context from the book. My best guess is that, even though the functions themselves are continuous, the pointwise limit is discontinuous on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The functions $f_m$ are integrable but not continuous.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, For every fixed $m$ $$f_m(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }m!x\text{ is integer} \\
0, & \text{if }m!x\text{ is not integer}
\end{cases}$$. Why $f_m$ is integrable?

Comment: @RFZ because each $f_m$ is continuous (in fact zero) except at countably many points.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Thanks a lot! :)